# How do I Bulkify Trigger to populate Opportunity Picklists with Account Picklists

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, bulkification, collection

I'm working on a requirement as follows: Whenever an Opportunity is created or edited, its custom region picklists (Region__c) should be overwritten with the Account region picklists (Region__c).

Trying to develop a trigger that would satisfy this requirement.

Whenever an Opportunity is created or edited, check to see if any of the custom Region__c picklists are NULL. If any are NULL, overwrite all picklist fields with corresponding data from the Account object.here's what I have so far:

```
trigger UpdateOpptyPicklists on Opportunity(Before Insert, Before Update) {
  for(Opportunity o: Trigger.new){
     Account a = [select id,Region__c,Area__c, Division__c from Account where Id=:o.AccountId];

    if(o.Region__c == NULL || o.Area__c == NULL || o.Division__c == NULL){

      o.Region__c=a.Region__c;
      o.Area__c = a.Area__c;
      o.Division__c=a.Division__c;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I bulkify this trigger

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would bulkify the trigger.  The key is to leverage Salesfroce collections (Lists, Sets, Maps) to hold your accounts, so you only have to use a single SOQL query, as opposed to a new SOQL query each iteration in your original trigger.  I am using a map to collect all the accounts and needed fields from the accounts, and then looping through the opps to reset there values if necessary.

```
trigger UpdateOpptyPicklists on Opportunity(Before Insert, Before Update) {

    map<Id,Account> accountMap = new map<Id,Account>();

    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New) {
        accountMap.put(o.AccountId, null);
    }
    accountMap.remove(null);
    accountMap.putAll([Select Id, Region__c, Area__c, Division__c from Account where Id In : accountMap.keyset()]);

    for(Opportunity o: Trigger.new){
        if(o.AccountId == null){
             continue;
        }
        if(o.Region__c == NULL || o.Area__c == NULL || o.Division__c == NULL){
            o.Region__c = accountMap.get(o.AccountId).Region__c;
            o.Area__c = accountMap.get(o.AccountId).Area__c;
            o.Division__ c = accountMap.get(o.AccountId).Division__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works when I create a new Opportunity. But it spits out an error when I try to save the Opportunity without selecting an Account. I still want to be able to create an Opportunity without selecting an Account. Also, it doesn't trigger when updating the Opportunity. How would I accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the code to not throw an error on an opportunity with no Account.  The code should work for an update.

Comment: No prb.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The key to making bulkified triggers is to make good use of key-value Maps.

So what I'd do is iterate through the (list of new) Opportunities and get a list of all the related Accounts:

`List< ID > AccIDs = new List< Id >();
For (Opportunity o: Trigger.new){
  AccIDs.add(o.AccountID);
}`

Then do a single query to grab all the Accounts, and save them into a Map

`Map< Id, Account > AccMap = new Map< Id, Account >([Select Id, Region__c, Area__c, Division__c from Account where ID in :AccIDs]);`

Now you can reference any account with the syntax `AccMap.get(o.AccountID)`

So what you want to do now is iterate through the opportunities again, and pull in the Account fields where needed:

`List< Opportunity > updateList = new List< Opportunity >();
For (Opportunity o: Trigger.new){
  if(o.Region__c == NULL || o.Area__c == NULL || o.Division__c == NULL){
      o.Region__c = AccMap.get(o.AccountID).Region__c;
      o.Area__c = AccMap.get(o.AccountID).Area__c;
      o.Division__c = AccMap.get(o.AccountID).Division__c;
      updateList.add(o);
   }
}
update(updateList);`

Hopefully that's enough to set you on the right track.  It takes a little practice to wrap your head around bulkification :)

Comment: Can you update this to use this pattern [Initialising Maps from Queries](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/initialising-maps-from-queries) rather than a loop?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a nice little trick.  Never knew about that!

I updated the above code with that change.

Answer (score 1):

Do this loop twice:

```
for(Opportunity o: Trigger.new){
```

The first time, get a Set of all of the different AccountIds.  After that, query for all of the associated accounts and place them in a Map with the Id as a key.  Loop through it a second time, use the map to grab the associated Account by it's Id.

Part 9:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices